# Vue 3 PropType doesn't see the interface

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I create parent component Product vue with onMonted hook:

```
setup () {
    let data = reactive({
      product: {},
      productInfo: {},
      loaded: false,
      shippingDate: ''
    })

    onMounted(async () => {
      const product = await findProduct()
      data.productInfo = productInfo(product)
      data.product = product
      data.loaded = true
    })

    return { data }
  },
```

And children component ProductAttributes

```
props: {
    product: {
      type: Object as PropType<Product>,
      required: true
    }
  },
  setup (props) {
    const configurableOptions = ref([])
    const configurableChildren = ref([])

    onMounted(() => {
      configurableChildren.value = props.product.configurable_children
      //@ts-ignore
      configurableOptions.value = props.product.configurable_options.map((option: ConfigurableOptions) => {
        option.values = option.values.sort((a: ConfigurableOptionsValue, b: ConfigurableOptionsValue) => {
          return parseInt(a.value_index) - parseInt(b.value_index)
        })
        return option
      })

      // resetAttrs()
    })

    return {
      configurableChildren,
      configurableOptions
    }
  }
```

But in this case typescript show me an error `Property 'configurable_children' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`But if I change setup function props to `setup (props: { product: Product }) {` and change props to`props: ['product']` typescript stops showing error.

Why is this happening? Why does typescript not extract the type from PropType?

PS I use defineComponent

Comment: Which version of vue are you using? Can you reproduce this in a dummy component? I've just tried out of curiosity on a component of mine and don't have the same issue.

Comment: An `unknown` prop usually indicates a problem in one of the `props` declarations, even a prop not relevant to the error at hand. Can you show the full declaration of the `props` option?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else encountering the error `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'unknown'` in this context, I was able to resolve it by upgrading my typescript version from `4.1.5` to `4.5.5`.

Comment: nop... this issue still exists!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is adding a default value with the type:

```
...
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object as PropType<IItemModel>,
      required: true,
      default: () => ({} as IItemModel)
    },
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Max Stevens is a savior. I was stuck in Vue 3 with typescript solving `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'unknown'`, so every time I passed property, in child component I did this:

**Parent:**

```
<some-component :b-prop="{known object 'B' with CustomInterface goes here}">
```

**Child:**

```
props: {
  bProp: Object as PropType<CustomInterface>,
  required: true
},
data () {
  return {
    b: this.bProp as CustomInterface
  }
},
created () {
  console.warn(b.customProperty) // no more errors of unknown
}
```

It was absolutely annoying, since each property required this additional "wrapping" in data.

After update to 4.5.5 the problem is gone. Now it's just `b: Object as PropType<CustomInterface>` without `bProp` and `data wrapper`
Great! Thanks!